# Prevent render before useEffect with search params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `Browse` that used to display search result requested from `SearchBar` component.

1. First search query when `results` state is `null`
2. Found some tracks now `results` state have array of tracks in
3. I make another search but changing the filter type from `By Tracks` to `By Users` (The results should have array of users objects)
4. I got an error because the render was called before the initResults() function so the results has always array of tracks object inside so I got error of undefined property

The output when I search for the first time :

```
> init useEffect
> render
```

The output when I searched another time inside the Browse Component :

```
> render
> init useEffect
```

How can I refresh the useEffect when search params change
Any idea ? Thank's !

**Browse.js**

```
export default function Browse() {
const [results, setResults] = UseSafeState(null)
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = UseSafeState(true)

const location = useLocation()
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)

const search = searchParams.get('search')
const identifierFilter = searchParams.get('identifier_filter')

const initResults = () => {
    setIsLoading(true)

    SearchAPI.search(search, identifierFilter)
        .then((response) => {
            setResults(response.data)
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setResults(null)
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
}

const renderTrackBrowse = () => {
    return results.map((result, key) => <div key={key}>{result.track.name}</div>)
}

const renderUserBrowse = () => {
    return results.map((result, key) => <div key={key}>{result.user.username}</div>)
}

const renderPage = () => {
    console.log('render')
    
    switch (identifierFilter) {
        case FiltersTypesSearchBar.TRACKS.name:
            return renderTrackBrowse()
        case FiltersTypesSearchBar.ARTIST_NAME.name:
            return renderUserBrowse()
        default:
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('init useEffect')
    initResults()
}, [location, search, identifierFilter])

return <div className="main double-contained browse">{isLoading ? <Loader /> : renderPage()}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effects will always execute after the execution of the whole function. Even `useLayoutEffect` does not get invoked early enough to fix your issue. But with a tiny change, your code would already work.

```
const renderPage = () => {
    console.log('render')

    // do not continue execution if no results exist
    if (!results) return;
    
    switch (identifierFilter) {
        case FiltersTypesSearchBar.TRACKS.name:
            return renderTrackBrowse()
        case FiltersTypesSearchBar.ARTIST_NAME.name:
            return renderUserBrowse()
        default:
    }
}
```

Also one of your dependencies in the `useEffect` seems to be irrelevant and could cause more requests to be done as necessary. This should be sufficient.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('init useEffect')
    initResults()
}, [search, identifierFilter])
```

Comment: Hi ! The problem is the results state is not null at this point, results have an array of users object, I can try to check the first index array if is a user object or track object in each case but I'm looking for a clean solution. I don't know if the information is important but I'm using navigate of useNavigate of react in the `SearchBar` Component to redirect to the `Browse` component when the search form is submited, I think that where the problem is come seeing that navigate don't refresh the page. What do you think ?

Comment: It is not clear where your hooks `UseSafeState` (by the way not a common name for a hook to start with an uppercase letter) and if the hook `useLocation` is also coming from the same package as your `useNavigate` then it shouldn't make any difference as the returned location will be updated correctly.